Dilemma about staying or leaving my current position
I'm a software engineer with over 5 years of experience, including 4 years in my current field and a couple as a freelancer. I've been with my current company for nearly as long as it's existed, about 5 years, and have significantly contributed to its growth, especially during tough times like COVID.
About 3 years ago, a senior employee recommended someone with no visible experience, who ended up being their romantic partner. This person, now a QA engineer, has consistently failed in their roles. We often receive bug reports from clients only after the product is in production.
This employee, thanks to their connection with a C-level executive, unjustifiably gained shares in the company and started acting like everyone's boss when the CEO isn't around. However, they switch to a "fragile" demeanor when the CEO is present.
Additionally, I discovered that a project I built alone was being used to funnel funds to the C-level executive, who then split the money with this coworker. I wouldn't mind if they kept the money for themselves as they have done a lot of work for the company and deserve to be rewarded, but splitting the fruits of my labor with someone who has consistently caused this company losses is not acceptable for me.
I am therefore considering to move to a new place of employment. I have received several good opportunities in the past, and now I am in the process of applying on Proxify which essentially triples my current salary. I have also talked with local companies for on-site jobs and got several amazing offers, one company even offered to pay for me to move closer to their office. I am still in considering, though, as I know that it would be extremely difficult to find a replacement for me, especially at the current salary range that the company is offering.
The CEO has probably gotten a hint from a recruiter that I am interviewing with other employers so he promised me a significant bonus recently, albeit it is 1/3 of the money for the project I am again developing solo, which is not a small amount at all, but knowing that the rest of the money will be redirected to the CTO and his useless manipulative girlfriend is driving me crazy.
So, should I straight up quit my job and go working for somebody else, or try to negotiate with the CEO to let go the individual who is bothering me and all other employees on daily basis?
I really do not see myself working in the same office with these people for more than a month. I will finsihs the current project, complete my Proxify application and send out my CV to more companies and put in my 2 weeks notice, unless something changes here because I am being driven insane every day I have to tolerate their unprofessional behavior, and their hypocrisy.
Edit: We aren't exactly Microsoft here, this is a small company with 9 employees, including interns. There is no management, HR or anything else.

Note that a CEO "funnelling" money from the fruits of the business is probably highly illegal. Assuming they are actually a CEO who ultimately reports to shareholders.

negotiate with the CEO to let go the individual who is bothering me You can't possibly be insane enough to think that this has a chance of ending well.

I am feeling the need to stay at this company because I am almost certain that it will fail without me. I don't want to end up being an a-hole, by acting that my ego is more important to me that the livelihood of 10 other people and their families, although it is - I will not be the one who compromises and stays, I will either leave the company and let it go to hell without me, or stay without the QA who doesn't do her job. I will not compromise for anything else.

@GregoryCurrie It wasn't the CEO, it was the CTO, and he was paid, then he took half the money and gave it to his girlfriend. The whole project was built by me. If the CTO kept the money for himself, I wouldn't care as he desrves it, but giving it to someone useless is a no no for me

@A.I.Breveleri I have been here for a longer time and done 10 times more work than her, I am more than comfortable that I am less replacable than someone who doesn't do anything.

This question comes off like a rant and like sour grapes, justified or not. Why would you stay if you have amazing offers? Why would you want to be the cause of someone else losing their job? That sounds like a hit job. Take one of the offers, move on, and forget about this place.

@joeqwerty Why would someone be employed and take money from the CEO and the other developers if they are useless? And I wouldn't care if I am the cause of someone else to lose their job if that someone doesn't do their job properly.

As far as I understood you, the girlfirend is not paid more by the company. The CTO gifted her his private money. If the CTO bought a set of expensive golf clubs instead of giving the money to his girlfriend, would that change something for you? Why is one expense better than the other? What if he would gift those golf clubs to his girlfriend?

Bad businesses must be allowed to experience the consequences of their bad decisions;  Otherwise they will make even greater bad decisions until it reaches a point that you cannot cover or protect.  Also, those bad decisions can get so bad that you get put in a legally compromised position.

Any consideration whatsoever of staying, or rationalizing staying (or the CTO embezzling funds), is a big mistake.

It’s not Illegal as the CEO of a company to hire friends and family or even to promote them. The world is built on companies filled with employees that are friends and family. If you feel burned by the company’s leadership. The last thing you should do is accept counter offers from leadership you don’t feel like you can trust. You won’t change their leadership style or their past decisions by accepting counteroffers. As for funneling profits, unless you have access to the money itself, it’s difficult for anyone to determine if that behavior is an actual problem. Most companies are 100% private

Unless you are THE one without whom the company will face a total shutdown, I do not see any discussion or bargaining with anyone will bring any positive results for you. This is an uphill battle, and any resistance from your side is going to be futile.
Choose one of the new offers, and move on. I admire your thoughtfulness about the business (more so the company being a smaller one), but at the end of the day, everyone need to look out for themselves. Let them stew in their own juice.

Thanks for the answer. I have been thinking of leaving, now most of the people in the thread have advised me to do so, and I will make the right decision.
I would also like to ask, if anyone has had similar experience, what to put as the reason for quitting my job if I do not want to cause any drama?

@Rrrassistant An exit interview is not an ideal place to establish your honesty. Rather, be "politically correct". Just say the boilerplate answer: "I got a better offer that is more aligned with my career visions" and leave it at that. No need to go into details and clarifications, best of luck!

It sounds like this is basically your first real job. ("I'm a software engineer with over 5 years of experience... I've been with my current company for nearly as long as it's existed, about 5 years...").
It can be really hard as a young person to detach from your first real job. You have a lot of your identity wrapped up in that position, and executives are more than happy to take advantage of it. (E.g.: "I discovered that a project I built alone was being used to funnel funds to the C-level executive... I wouldn't mind if they kept the money for themselves as they have done a lot of work for the company" is pretty Stockholm-syndromey.)
The situation sounds crappy. If you can get a position that triples your current salary -- yes, you should probably take it, and most high-level professionals would jump ship in a second.
For a similar example of a worker at their first job finding it hard to disconnect, see this question.

Thanks for sharing your opinion. I am 100% thinking of jumping ship after I finish my current project, as I am the only developer that can finish it - everyone else is either too junior or working with different technologies. I will not accept starting any new projects, and the most I will provide after my departure is vetting my replacement.

@Rrrassistant Finishing the project is not your responsibility.Stop caring. And especially don't let them know you plan to leave by "not accept starting any new projects".
